# Why is this error in SQLiteStudio showing up?

Tags: sql, sqlitestudio

I made a table in SQLiteStudio in DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "City " 
(
    Name STRING,
    Population INTEGER,
    Country STRING,
    Elevation INTEGER
);
```

However, when I start doing queries such as this:

```
Select AVG(Elevation)
From 'City'
Where Country='Germany';
```

This error will show up:

> Error while executing SQL query on database'': no such table:

Is this because I wrote the syntax wrong or a setting in SQLiteStudio?

Comment: Don't use single quotes around the table name in your query.

Comment: Check the name of the table you created (City) and make sure it doesn't have a space at the end as specified in your CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your query.  The first is the single quotes.  But, you have a space in the name of the table.  So, to query it, you might need to use the space:

```
Select AVG(Elevation)
From "City "
Where Country = 'Germany';
```

However, that is really, really silly.  Just fix the table by removing the quotes when defining it:

```
CREATE TABLE City (
    Name STRING,
    Population INTEGER,
    Country STRING,
    Elevation INTEGER
);
```

To keep your life simple, just give columns and tables names that don't need to be quoted.  Then, you don't ever need to use quotes when referring to them.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the space in the name that I did realize earlier.